# I want to skip significant number of first video frames before playing/reading any video file.

Tags: c++, opencv

To observe video frames after approximately 12 minutes of running, I want to skip all the frames before 12 minutes. Can any one help me .Can any one help me to do that? I am beginnger in c++/openCV

Comment: What have you done so far? (You almost certainly will have to read the frame headers at least for the frames you want to skip, as frames are variable size, so unless the format you are using has some sort of index to tell "where the next n seconds start", you will need to somehow process a frame just to skip it)

Comment: I have video of format .avi.@ M Petersson

Comment: That wasn't the "what have you done so far" answer I was looking for. Maybe you could explain what programming you have done to actually try to solve the problem...

Comment: I did nothing but try to solve the problem using c++/ openCV@ m Petersson

Answer (score 1):

You didnt tell whether you are using a Video File or a Stream as input.

for a file:

use a `cv::VideoCapture cap;` object, open the file and call `cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 12*60*1000);` where 12*60*1000 are 12 minutes in milliseconds.

to access the next frame you can then use `cap >> myMat;` where myMat is a `cv::Mat`

for C API you would call `cvSetCaptureProperty(CvCapture* capture, int property_id, double value)` which should be `cvSetCaptureProperty(capt, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC, 12*60*1000);` in your example. Same for capt2, capt3 etc. No guarantee, since i didnt use the C API since a hundred years ;)

Comment: IplImage *camImages1;
IplImage *camImages2;
IplImage *camImages3;
CvCapture *capt;
CvCapture *capt2;
CvCapture *capt3;
capt = cvCreateFileCapture("E:\\data\\20140916\\camImage1.avi");
capt2 =cvCreateFileCapture("E:\\data\\20140916\\camImage2.avi");
capt3 =cvCreateFileCapture("E:\\data\\20140916\\camImage0.avi");  camImages1 = cvQueryFrame(capt);
camImages2 = cvQueryFrame(capt2);
camImages3 = cvQueryFrame(capt3); from here I want to skip several minutes of video from the beginning @Micka

Comment: do you really have to use IplImages and the old C api? everything is much easier in the C++ API ;)

Comment: My main program is written in cuda file, whole coding is developed with c api Micka

Comment: click the "arrow up" symbol at the beginning of the answer. If everything works, you can "accept" the answer in addition.